# Out of memory error on back button

Tags: android, android-imageview

I'm creating a slideshow app, which loads an image at a time in a ViewFlipper by using the animation event to switch between images in the same ImageView, however when I press the back button to leave the app, I always get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  729): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(  729): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:650)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:389)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:449)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at br.com.vodia.mobilephotoframe.ConfigFragment.onActivityCreated(ConfigFragment.java:167)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1486)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1877)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:552)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1167)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5216)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3553)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1233)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)

E/AndroidRuntime(  729):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here is part of my code:

```
 mSlideshow = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.slideshow);
        if (currentImages.size() > 0) {
            mSlideshow.setFlipInterval(interval);
            mSlideshow.setInAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
            mSlideshow.setOutAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out);

            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            mWidth = size.x;
            mHeight = size.y;

            mSlideshowImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.slideshow_image);

            mImageList = new ArrayList<String>(currentImages);

            mCurrentImage = 0;

            mCurrentBitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(mImageList.get(mCurrentImage), mWidth, mHeight);
            mSlideshowImage.setImageBitmap(mCurrentBitmap);


            mSlideshow.getInAnimation().setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    if (mCurrentImage + 1 < mImageList.size()) {
                        mCurrentImage = mCurrentImage + 1;
                    } else {
                        mCurrentImage = 0;
                    }

                    if (mCurrentBitmap != null)
                        mCurrentBitmap.recycle();

                    mCurrentBitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromPath(mImageList.get(mCurrentImage), mWidth, mHeight);
                    mSlideshowImage.setImageBitmap(mCurrentBitmap);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
            });

            mSlideshow.startFlipping();
        }
```

This code already uses inSampleSize to limit the width and height of the bitmap to the display resolution.

Comment: Please have a look at this tutorial made by google http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: are you displaying previous image on onBackPressed() or moving to previous activity?

Comment: @KaranNagpal I'm recycling the bitmap object on onBackPressed.

Comment: did you get the same error while testing on physical device?

Comment: recycling delete the object reference but doesn't free up the space it is using and that space can not be used until garbage collector is not called, use System.gc() just after invoking recycle() method. [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()) is the doc. for recycle method.

Comment: Calling System.gc() does solve the problem, but I don't think garbage collecting every time the user press the back button a good way to fix this. Do I have another option?